# What does it mean for Redis to be an "in memory" database?

Tags: redis

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) that Redis is an in-memory database, but it also says that it can persist "data to the disk at least every 2 seconds".  I feel like these two things are mutually exclusive.  How can it be considered in-memory yet (it can) store data on disk?  I assumed the definition of in-memory meant that **it does not** store to disk.

---

This is a similar question: [Redis concept: In memory or DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151866/redis-concept-in-memory-or-db)  The difference is that he's asking about the persistence implementation.  My question is about the concept of in-memory vs persistence.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Redis is an in-memory but persistent on disk database, so it represents a different trade off where very high write and read speed is achieved with the limitation of data sets that can't be larger than memory. Another advantage of in memory databases is that the memory representation of complex data structures is much simpler to manipulate compared to the same data structure on disk, so Redis can do a lot, with little internal complexity. At the same time the two on-disk storage formats (RDB and AOF) don't need to be suitable for random access, so they are compact and always generated in an append-only fashion (Even the AOF log rotation is an append-only operation, since the new version is generated from the copy of data in memory).

http://redis.io/topics/faq

In redis, all data has to be in memory. This is the point which is totally different from other NoSQL. Usually when you access and read some data in a database, you don't know if the data is in memory (cache) or not, but in the case of Redis, it's guaranteed that all data is in memory. Writing to disk is optional, which you can think of as having the trunk on memory and a kind of backup on the disk. You may lose data which is saved after last saving to a disk if you suddenly turn off the server.

And of course the advantage of it is a performance. Since all data is in RAM, it's incredibly fast.

Comment: OK so what happens if I have 10GB of RAM but I want to store 20GB in Redis?

Comment: I looked at that faq and I'm getting the impression it works like this: "The whole dataset must fit on memory and persistence is used as a backup in case of an emergency.  But, you can never store more than the size of your RAM in Redis".  Is that accurate?

Comment: regarding previous comment, virtual memory is deprecated - version 2.4 was the last to support this feature (2011)

Comment: @DanielKaplan After 10GB(although you can't really hit all the RAM, there are other things that need to run) any operation which requires more memory will throw error. Reads will succeed. Flushing to disk is so that you can recover redis after crash/restart. Replication still goes to RAM so no disk there. Sharding goes to RAM so no disk there. Persistence is just for recovery. You can't read from that persistence.

Answer (score 9):

They are not mutually exclusive. In-memory means all the data is stored in memory for it to be accessed. It doesn't mean that it should be impossible to also store it on to the disk from time to time, but it definitely shouldn't be accessed from the disk unless some exceptional events occur.
When data is read, it can either be read from the disk or from memory. In Redis's case, it's always retrieved from memory (hence - in-memory database).
Writing the data onto the disk every two seconds is useful for having a backup in case of outage. On one end, the users accessing the database are accessing the data stored in memory, also, the backup mechanism accesses the data from the memory and writes it to the disk.
In case of a system failure, the data stored in memory is lost. But when booting up, the data (up to the last 2 seconds) is retrieved from the disk and stored into memory again for the applications to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Redis is an In-Memory Database(IMDB) as it relies on main memory of computer for data storage while others use Disk Storage database mechanism. That is why Redis is faster than disk-optimized databases because disk access is slower than memory access.

Answer (score 1):

For performance it keeps and store data in memory. But as Redis is a NoSQL based on key-value pairs, it also give you an option to persist on disk.

Comment: That didn't really clarify anything to me.  Why doesn't this make it a "NoSQL Database"?  Instead, it's a "NoSQL in-memory database", and I don't understand why.

Comment: Is persisting data on Disk is required for a DB to be NoSQL? I don't think so. Please prove me wrong by providing some reference.

Answer (score 1):

In-memory database is positioned between web client and the back-end db (for examples, MySQL, or DynamoDB, Hbase, etc.). When client sends a query to web server, usually, the web server will need to query MySQL for results. Redis (or Memcached) provides a buffer for such queried results. Therefore, web server only needs to go through the key-value pairs stored in Redis/Memcached ( stored in memory ) to get results. The key is usually a hash code of a specific query, the value is the queried result.

There may be other ways of using Redis. But the basic idea is the same: faster look-up than on-disk database.